# Does Sencha ExtJS classic toolkit supports responsive design?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6-classic

Ext JS 6 supports the responsive design. We can use both responsive plugin and media queries to make an app responsive. But all documentation are mentioning modern toolkit. Does classic toolkit support responsive design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Ext.plugin.Responsive](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.plugin.Responsive.html?) with classic toolkit.